# Writing my function to a txt file return 'None' in txt file but the desired result in terminal

Tags: python, function, output

I understand that this is a newbie question, I am a newbie.
I have a function that takes a list of URLs and formats them into HTML tables. I want the output of the function to be on an existing TXT file.
I tried putting the function as the .write input but it only writes 'None' in the file. I understood that its because my function is basically empty as it only write and keeps it nowhere, but i have trouble solving that. using the return instead of print doesn't work. The function does write the result into the Terminal prefectly.

```
def test2(strList):
  d = defaultdict(int)
  for k in strList:
    d[k] += 1
  print('<table>')
  for i in d.items():
    print(
      '<tr><td><img src="{0[0]}"</td><td><img src="{0[1]}"</td></tr>'.format(i))
  print('</table>')
```

and thats the writing code

```
f = open("albumshtml.txt", "w")
f.write(str(test2(img)))
f.close()
```

ive tried using append instead of w, same result. how can i save the function without printing until i want it to write to the TXT file?
again, im new to it don't scold me please.

Comment: Instead of the print, declare a variable in your function of the type string. Then append the parameters of your print function. When you are done, just return this variable.

Comment: `test2` has no explicitely set `return` value, so it returns the default `None`

Comment: Better yet, pass the file you want to write to as an argument.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to indicate that it's solved. You can instead accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to returning the string is to pass the file you want to write to as an argument (which can default to `sys.stdout` to preserve the current behavior).

```
import sys
import contextlib


def test2(strList, f=sys.stdout):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for k in strList:
        d[k] += 1
    print('<table>', file=f)
    for i in d.items():
        print(
          '<tr><td><img src="{0[0]}"</td><td><img src="{0[1]}"</td></tr>'.format(i), file=f)
    print('</table>', file=f)


with open("albumshtml.txt", "w") as f:
    test2(img, f)

with open("albumshtml.txt", "w") as f:
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
        test2(img)
```

The `redirect_stdout` trick can also be used without modifying `test2`, since `print` writes to `sys.stdout` when the `file` keyword argument is not used.

You can also use `redirect_stdout` *inside* `test2` to avoid having to repeat the `file` argument on every call to `print`.

```
def test2(strList, f=sys.stdout):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for k in strList:
        d[k] += 1
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
        print('<table>')
        for i in d.items():
            print(
              '<tr><td><img src="{0[0]}"</td><td><img src="{0[1]}"</td></tr>'.format(i))
        print('</table>')


with open("albumshtml.txt", "w") as f:
    test2(img, f)
```

Comment: Did just that and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list to save the result and finally use the method [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join) to concatenate the string elements in the list.

```py
def test2(strList):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for k in strList:
        d[k] += 1
    res_list = ['<table>']
    for i in d.items():
        res_list.append(
            '<tr><td><img src="{0[0]}"</td><td><img src="{0[1]}"</td></tr>'.format(i)
        )
    res_list.append('</table>')
    return "".join(res_list)
```